# JQuery ajax and dom issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to add a row to a table.  Within the row is an element who's click event I am capturing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var newRow = "<tr> ... </tr>";
    $('tableName > tbody:last').append(newRow);

   $(...).click( function() { // click event on newly inserted elem in the row
      alert("click");
   });
}
```

This works great and the alert comes up as expected.  BUT when I now add the new row dynamically via an ajax call and parsing the xml, it stops working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   getData();

   $(...).click( function() { // click event on newly inserted elem in the row
      alert("click");
   });

   function getData() {
      $.ajax({
          ...
          success: function(data) {
             //parse the xml

             $('tableName > tbody:last').append(parsedXml);
          }
   });
}
```

The html is correctly added to the DOM, but the click event is no longer captured.  Is there some issue with scope or closures going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
 $(...).live('click', function() { // click event on newly inserted elem in the row
      alert("click");
   });
```

This keeps the click event running after it has been used

[more info](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: wow that worked thanks! Can you explain why this worked? I mean, I am creating the click handler after the dom element was created...  either way ill accept your answer when it lets me

Comment: Oh, is it because the ajax call is asynchronous? So essentially, the dom isn't really being created before registering the handler

Comment: essentially .live() is needed when new elements are being added to the page, whether with ajax or even just an element you add within your click function. Basic rule of thumb, if your dom is changing use .live(). Check out the more info link in my answer for, well, more info :)

Answer (score 1):

When working with a table, I like to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for this. It's very similar to `.live()`, but lets you set up an event listener on a single *parent* element, rather than individual handlers on every child element. So whether you have a table of one row or 1000, you still need only one handler.

```
$('#yourtable').delegate('your_descendant_element','click', function(){
   alert("click"); 
});
```

Comment: I'd agree with `.delegate()` over `.live()`. If the new elements are all in a table, then might as well limit the handler to the click events in that table instead of the entire document. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using the live() event handler.  It allows you to create an event that matches elements created in the future dynamically, which is what is not happening right now.  Another way to fix it would be to move the all to bind down below where you append the new table row, but live() is a much better answer.